# Determine period and angle of harmonic oscillator with $x = 2 \pi \sin(120 \pi t + 3.2 t)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, harmonic-oscillator

A particle moving under simple harmonic motion has displacement
$$x = 2 \pi \sin(120 \pi t + 3.2 t) \, .$$

How can I determine the period and the phase angle?

Comment: What's the period of $\sin(t)$ and how does that change when you go to $\sin(at)$?

Answer (score 1):

Don't be confused by the PI in the argument of the sine. You can write this in standard form sin(ωt) if you combine the two terms. In other words

ω = 120π + 3.2

where  P=2π/ω. That should get you started.

Answer (score -1):

Any sine wave has the form

$$ y(t) = A\sin\left(\omega t + \phi\right), $$

where $A$ is the amplitude, $\omega$ is the angular frequency, and $\phi$ is the phase angle. The angular frequency has the relationship

$$ \omega = \frac{2\pi}{P}, $$

where $P$ is the period. You can factor the argument to your sine function in order to determine $P$ and $\phi$.